# Access Userform Value field list issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, userform

**Hi, I have almost 40 yes/no questions, so I have created the form using the table "data", each field in data table I selected"yes/No" data type. Now after completing the form creation, when I select first question or any of the question as yes/no , rest all of the questions getting no selected. Is this something can you help me with?**

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with above question

Answer (score 0):

Yes/No datatype usually set to No as its default value.
There are two type of controls you can use on form to represent Yes/No data type: option and checkbox.
If the control is bound, it will shows its field default value on current record which is 'No'.

In your case, i prefer to use unbound controls and vba to manage form interaction and save answered data into table.